# How do I send multiple files in same key in multi part formdata

Tags: php, httprequest

I need to send multiple files in post request through curl but I need them to be identified through same key. Something like below

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryyFeHAIcdy1Bny0xj
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="blah[attachments][][resource]"; filename="abc.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundaryyFeHAIcdy1Bny0xj
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="blah[attachments][][resource]"; filename="def.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

I am currently doing this like

```
$abc['blah[attachments][][resource]'] => new CurlFile($pathToImage,'image/jpeg')
```

which works fine for single file but how do I send request like above for multiple files?

Comment: Turn `$abc['blah[attachments][][resource]']` into  `$abc['blah[attachments][0][resource]']`, `$abc['blah[attachments][1][resource]']`, etc. for each file.

Comment: well I am working with external API and that is what is expected. Have tried on my machine works for my local test script.